# Larger Civi mailouts getting stuck

Tags: civimail, drupal, smtp

Fairly new to Civi still. Have taken over a Drupal 7 site with Civi. Drupal 7.97 and Civi 5.39 (aware this needs updating). The client sends regular mailouts to anything up to 1000 recipients and this was working fine until recently. Now mailouts get to around 50% and stick. SMTP settings are fine and verified, individual emails send, I can create smaller test mailouts to 5-10 recipients and they work but the larger ones just stop working. The SMTP service (Mailersend) says no issues their end and the host (Krystal) says no issues with them. I thought maybe CRON was overloading so I reduced the frequency and CiviMail batch settings to just send a few at a time but this doesn't help.

In Drupal recent log messages I see the following:

```
SMTP Socket Error or failed to set sender error. Message: Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 450, response: Message not queued: recipient is suppressed)], Code: 10006

Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: 10006, Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 450, response: Message not queued: recipient is suppressed)]
```

These would all imply SMTP settings are wrong but they aren't.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks,

Rob